# Как сохранить программно созданные элементы при повороте экрана?

Tags: android, onsaveinstancestate

Друзья, доброго времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста как сохранить программно созданные элементы при повороте экрана? Знаю как с помощь onSaveInstanceState и onRestoreInstanceState сохранять данные, но как положить объект в пакет я не знаю, буду благодарен за любой развернутый ответ, Спасибо!
Ниже код приложения:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button button1;
    LinearLayout container;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                LayoutInflater li1 = getLayoutInflater();

                View it1 = li1.inflate(R.layout.row, container, false);

                container.addView(it1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

Comment: на хабре [недавно статья была](https://habr.com/ru/post/489746/?_ga=2.211018194.690500599.1583038315-1823904184.1568032133) на эту тему

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класть тяжёлые объекты в бандлы не самая лучшая идея.

Размер бандла органичен (1мб было раньше, возможно сейчас уже больше).

И это является плохой практикой. Лучшим решением является либо сохранение данных в какой-то другой сущности, а бандл класть к примеру его id для того чтоб после поворота снова это вытянуть.

Это может быть сохранение в базу данных. Либо это может быть какая-то сущность которая не умирает вместе с вашей View, например Presenter или ViewModel.

Если же вы все же хотите положить в бандл то лучше отдавать предпочтение Parcelable перед Serialaizeble. Так как парселизация проходит быстрее и не использует рефлексию.

Comment: объекты совсем не тяжелые, максимум две-три вьюхи с коротким текстом

Comment: Ну выбор конечно за вами. Я описал практики которые более хороши, но всегда необходимо отталкиваться от задачи. Не стоит городить архитектуру в приложении на 2 экрана. С другой стороны там где 2 экрана через пол года может оказаться 20. В общем все надо смотреть в контексте задачи

Comment: А не поделитесь примером, где это реализовано? Я просто чайник на этом этапе(

Comment: Что именно? Parcelable?

Comment: Помещение id View в бандл, и последующее его извлечение после поворота

Comment: Ну c id тут подразумевается что вы где-то эти обьекты (в вашем случае View) храните отдельно. Допустим у вас есть база в которой 100 обьектов хранится и вы хотите при повороте сохранить состояние экрана. Вы сохраняете id вашего объекта, а после поворота снова идете в базу и тянете именно тот объект который был последним. А просто так это не получится. Второй вопрос, зачем вам хранить вью? Сохраните состояние вью, а восстановите. НАпример в текст вью сохраните  текст и снова его задайте после поворота

Comment: И сами вью обычно и так сохраняют свое состояние после поворота если у них в XML Заданы id-шники. Если конечно это не какая-то ваша сложная View

Comment: Да, но у меня динамически созданные объекты, которые создаются по нажатию кнопки, как например View it1 в моем коде в примере

Comment: Ну передавать в бандл ваши View это однозначно плохая идея. Я бы все же создавал ваши View каждый раз по новой, сохраняя лишь данные которые дадут мне понять сколько View предварительно было создано и с какими параметрами.  Например если бы я динамически создавал ImageView то я бы хранил какой-то список где при каждом добавлении в него добавлялось бы ссылка на картинку. А передавать список в активити уже по критериям из ответа.

Comment: Если View параметры View более сложны чем стринга, то создал бы для этого отдельный объект с параметрами View и хранил бы список этих объектов.

Comment: Сергей, спасибо, вроде понял))

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы положить объект в бандл, нужно наследовать его (объект) от `Serializable` или `Parcelable`. Или ложить только данные из этого объекта и после уже восстанавливать всё, создавая новый объект и заполняя его восстановленными данными.